# MySQL string contains string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL Workbench and I'm currently looking for a function or something that helps me check if a string is within another string.
For example:

`text1 = 'hello , name , world';`

If I have a string or `varchar` that is something like this

`'My name is'`

It should say that it contains since it has 'name' on it.
Basically what I'm trying to do is I have a Comments table and I'm creating a trigger before insert on Comments that checks if the `comment_text` contains any swear words. These swear words are saved like this

> select group_concat(word) into texto from reserved_words;

So it has all the words close to each other: swear1,swear2,swear3,etc

I want it to update a certain table if the comment really contains a swear word.
I've tried to use `LIKE, SUBSTR(),CONTAINS(),REGEXP` without any success.

Can someone help?

Comment: Can you put some example queries with data out here so we know what you tried?

Comment: Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 9):

`LIKE` is what you want. You need to wrap it with `%` to match anywhere in the string.

```
WHERE string LIKE '%name%'
```

will be true if the value of the `string` column contains the string `name`.

If you have the swear words in a column of a table, you can join them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT comment
FROM comments AS c
JOIN swear_words AS s ON c.comment LIKE CONCAT('%', s.word, '%')
```

Don't put the swear words into a comma-separated list, that makes it very difficult to work with them individually in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
where comment regexp replace(swearwords, ',', '|')
```

You may or may not want to include word delimiters in the regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Build your regex pattern from `reserved_words` table:

```
select CONCAT('(',group_concat(word SEPARATOR '|'),')') from reserved_words
```

And then run `REGEXP` check against the `comment` field.

**DEMO RUN**

```
create table reserved_words(word varchar(10));
insert into reserved_words values('hello'),('name'),('world');

select 'My name is' REGEXP (select CONCAT('(',group_concat(word SEPARATOR '|'),')') from reserved_words) swear
UNION ALL
select 'My title is' REGEXP (select CONCAT('(',group_concat(word SEPARATOR '|'),')') from reserved_words) swear
UNION ALL
select 'hello world' REGEXP (select CONCAT('(',group_concat(word SEPARATOR '|'),')') from reserved_words) swear;
```

**RESULT**

```
swear
1
0
1
```